# How to use v-model in quill editor

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I use Vue 3

I used this before. It worked just fine.

```
<textarea v-model="description" required></textarea>
```

But I changed it to this

```
<QuillEditor
v-model="description" required
/>
```

In QuillEditor, many factors such as placeholder worked well, but only v-model didn't work.

Is this simply a dependency issue? If not, how should I change it?

I downloaded it from https://vueup.github.io/vue-quill/guide/installation.html#cdn

If this is a simple dependency problem, is there a solution? If not, could you recommend another vue3 compatible editor? (Images may be attached)

Comment: According to the docs it looks like you need to use `v-model:content`? [Docs](https://vueup.github.io/vue-quill/api/#v-model-content)

Comment: @Quiver I tried, but it didn't work.

Comment: It seems like you have a problem somewhere else in your code then. It doesn't seem likely that it's related to Quill. If you could reproduce your problem on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) then we might be able to help more.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

you can use the component like this:

```
<quill-editor v-model:content="modelname" contentType="html" theme="snow"></quill-editor>
```

For more info check: https://vueup.github.io/vue-quill/api/#v-model-content

Answer (score 3):

here's how you should fix it :

```
<quill-editor v-model:content="modelname" contentType="html" />
```

Answer (score 1):

just sharing my finding as below:

because of quill-editor component default content Type is "delta", but if you want to assign value ( string type ), then you need to change the content type from delta to text or html

by API props "content" or "v-model:content"
set the string value on quill-editor component

1. set the contentType props to "text" or "html" on component
2. use the :content or :v-model:content" to pass the string value to quill-editor component

referral link: https://vueup.github.io/vue-quill/api/

Answer (score -3):

## You can use this editor. I am using this editor and it's work's.

Visit - https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue3-editor

### Instruction -

1. npm i vue3-editor (install it)
2. import { VueEditor } from "vue3-editor"; (use on specific component)
3. components: {VueEditor}, (use in component)
4. (use this in form)

thank you!!

Comment: Even though I use vue3, 'This dependency was not found' occurs after npm install vue3-editor.